# Pass operation from user control to Worker_DoWork in other window

Tags: wpf, events, delegates

I am just new woking with ProgressBar in WPF. I have a user control like this:

```
public partial class Import : UserControl
{

    public Import()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void filePickerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Create the OpenFIleDialog object
        Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openPicker = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        // Add file filters
        // We are using excel files in this example
        openPicker.DefaultExt = ".xslt";
        openPicker.Filter = "Excel Files|*.xls;*.xlsx;*.xlsm";

        // Display the OpenFileDialog by calling ShowDialog method
        Nullable<bool> result = openPicker.ShowDialog();

        // Check to see if we have a result 
        if (result == true)
        {
            // Application now has read/write access to the picked file
            filePathTextBox.Text = openPicker.FileName.ToString();
        }
    }

    private void btn_Import_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        //import all data from excel file to datatable
        Workbook wb = new Workbook(filePathTextBox.Text);

        // Accessing the worksheet in the Excel file
        Worksheet worksheetPro = wb.Worksheets[1];

        Worksheet worksheetCat = wb.Worksheets[0];

        // Exporting all data by ExportDataTable
        DataTable dataTablePro = worksheetPro.Cells
            .ExportDataTable(1, 0, worksheetPro.Cells.Rows.Count - 1, worksheetPro.Cells.Columns.Count, false);

        DataTable dataTableCat = worksheetCat.Cells
            .ExportDataTable(1, 0, worksheetCat.Cells.Rows.Count - 1, worksheetCat.Cells.Columns.Count, false);

        //dump data from datatable to SQL server
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-L6OBVA4\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=QLDB;Integrated Security=True";
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
            {
                //mapping columns of Datatable with the name of DB
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(dataTablePro.Columns[0].ColumnName, "Tên");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(dataTablePro.Columns[1].ColumnName, "Giá");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(dataTablePro.Columns[2].ColumnName, "Số Lượng");
                bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add(dataTablePro.Columns[3].ColumnName, "Miêu Tả");

                //set the destination table name in DB will be affected
                bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Products";

                try
                {
                    //coppy all rows from nominated datatable and dump it to DB
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTablePro);
                    dataTablePro.Clear();
                    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopyCat = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
                    {
                        bulkCopyCat.ColumnMappings.Add(dataTableCat.Columns[0].ColumnName, "Loại");
                        bulkCopyCat.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Categories";
                        bulkCopyCat.WriteToServer(dataTableCat);
                        dataTableCat.Clear();
                        MessageBox.Show("Success!!!");
                    }                          
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The purpose of this user control is: Choose an excel file, then import all data to datatable, finally, dump all data to SQL server. I need to make a processing bar for operation of dumping from datatable to SQL server cause I think it takes long time. So next thing, I create a Process bar window:

```
public partial class ProgressBar : Window
{
    public ProgressBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
        worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;

        worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            (sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress(i);
            //do my operation here
        }
    }

    void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        pbStatus.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
}
```

you can see above snippet code, I have a method named:

> worker_DoWork()

it is where I plan to put my operation. And the last thing, I want to take these code lines from user control then put it into worker_DoWork() cause I think these lines take time to handle:

```
try
                {
                    //coppy all rows from nominated datatable and dump it to DB
                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dataTablePro);
                    dataTablePro.Clear();
                    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopyCat = new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
                    {
                        bulkCopyCat.ColumnMappings.Add(dataTableCat.Columns[0].ColumnName, "Loại");
                        bulkCopyCat.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Categories";
                        bulkCopyCat.WriteToServer(dataTableCat);
                        dataTableCat.Clear();
                        MessageBox.Show("Success!!!");
                    }                          
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
```

what should I do to get it? I heard about delegate and event can give me a choice but i could not find it out by myself. Thanks!

Comment: Do not inherit from Window for your ProgressBar. If you must inherit make it a user control and put it in your main window so you can make it overlap with the rest by changing Visibility property. Then bind that visibility property to some static Visibility property that you will change when button is clicked. This is of course if you want 1 instace of ProgressBar

Comment: @MatijaK. i got it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not care about multiple instances of progress dialog. Then try something like this:

**Import.xaml:**

```
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="filePicker" Content="ClickMe" Click="filePicker_Click" DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <ProgressBar x:Name="progressBar" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="75"  DockPanel.Dock="Top" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    </Grid>
```

**Import.xaml.cs**:

```
    private void filePicker_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        // here you call your batch code
        var task = new Task(() => Thread.Sleep(3000));
        // after task is done hide progress dialog
        task.ContinueWith(x => Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() => this.progressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed)));
        task.Start();
    }
```

(I did not bother with updating the status. It is always 75%.).